How to get Azure DevOps user contact email by API
I would like to get all user contact email in Azure DevOps.
First, I tried to use https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/_apis/graph/users API to get all users. I can see all of user info, but the mailAddress for each user is not the contact email address for each user.
Then I tried to use https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/me to get my user profile. It did return correct info including my contact email in emailAddress attribute
But when I tried to use https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles to get all user info, I get error
{
    "count": 1,
    "value": {
        "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
    }
}

I couldn't find any documents to indicate how I can get all user profile, including contact email from Azure API service. Does anyone have any clue for the solution?
Here is the where the contact email I refer to in Azure DevOps


Users - List will give you a list of users. For each one invoke Users - Get to get user details including the email. You need to set the descriptor in the endpoint, which is returned by the first endpoint.

Thanks @RuiJarimba. Like I said, I use Users - List to get user list, but it only contains mailAddress attribute, usually is same as principalName, my actual contact email is not same as this mailAddress, which you can get your contact email from https://api.veracode.com/api/authn/v2/users/self. If you update your contact email, you can double check the mailAddress in the first API call does not get changed.

The contact email is on user level, it's typically the one you used to sign into Azure DevOps, but you can change it to different from profile page.
Unfortunately there's no method to get all user contact emails.  The user needs to check own contact email.
I totally understand your concern, if you would like the feature, it's recommended to raise a feature request on community link, thanks.
